# SSL decryption error while using GRPC

Tags: java, node.js, ssl, grpc, grpc-java

I am using GRPC version: 1.1.2 & JDK version:1.8 on the GRPC client connecting to a NodeJS server.  The Java client is able to connect fine but I always see the exception below on the server side when I disconnect from the client.

**exception (only on server)**

```
E0410 15:03:19.674531000 140735121084416 ssl_transport_security.c:439] SSL_read returned 0 unexpectedly.
E0410 15:03:19.674829000 140735121084416 secure_endpoint.c:185]        Decryption error: TSI_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I am shutting down the GRPC Java connection with the following call:

```
channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  //channel is ManagedChannel
```

Should I be cleaning up any other resources before making this call or should I use an alternate mechanism to disconnect cleanly from the server?

**Edit**
I noticed that I get the same error when I try the following as well:

```
channel.shutdown();
```

I am using OpenSSL on Mac - I recall changing the default Mac version (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016).

**secure_endpoint.c in grpc**

```
 result = tsi_frame_protector_unprotect(ep->protector, message_bytes,
                                             &processed_message_size, cur,
                                             &unprotected_buffer_size_written);
      gpr_mu_unlock(&ep->protector_mu);
      if (result != TSI_OK) {
        gpr_log(GPR_ERROR, "Decryption error: %s",
                tsi_result_to_string(result));
        break;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagedChannel.shutdown()` indicates to the server that no more new RPCs should be started.  All existing RPCs, especially streaming RPCs will continue to run.  Once all those RPCs are completed, `ManagedChannel` will close all the underlying connections and the channel will enter the terminated state.

ManagedChannel was designed to be similar to `ExecutorService`.   One thing you can do to make sure that you really are shutting down properly is call awaitTermination in a loop:

```
while (!channel.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.Second)) {
  System.err.println("Still not terminated.");
}
```

Comment: thanks  - is there a clean way of finishing off bidirectional streams from client side when the client needs to disconnect?

Comment: or is the only option to shutdown the channel from the client and the server has to detect the client disconnect and close the stream?

Comment: You can call onCompleted() from the StreamObserver for the stream.